# PySpark Querying Multiple JSON Files

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have uploaded into `Spark 2.2.0`  many JSONL files (the structure is the same for all of them) contained in a directory using the command (python spark): df = spark.read.json(mydirectory) df.createGlobalTempView("MyDatabase") sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM MyDatabase") sqlDF.show().

The uploading works, but when I query sqlDF (`sqlDF.show()`), it seems that Spark counts the rows of just one file (the first?) and not those of all of them. I am assuming that "MyDatabase" is a dataframe containing all the files.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the json file?

Answer (score 0):

If I upload just one file consisting of only one line of multiple json objects {...}, Spark can properly identify the tabular structure. If I have more than one file, I have to put each {} on a new line to get the same result.